# How I can say correctly to my boss that I want to go to vacation?

Tags: prepositions, passive-voice

I want to ask to my boss that I want to go to vacation, because I'm very tired. How I can say it correctly to my boss. It's my version:

> I'm very tired. I haven't gone to vacation a long time. There is need to me to go to vacation.

Comment: Side note: instead of chief, you probably mean "boss". Your boss is the person who you work for, and a chief is the guy in a tribe with the feathered head-dress.

Comment: You can use the word *holiday* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/holiday_1?q=holiday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm very tired.

This is fine. But it doesn't perfectly convey the idea that you are over-worked. Being tired could just mean you need a day off to get some sleep.

> I haven't gone to vacation a long time.

In this case, "gone to" is incorrect. You don't go TO a vacation, you go ON a vacation.

I would phrase this one of two ways (both are fine):

- I haven't gone **on a** vacation **in** a long time.
- I haven't **been on** vacation **in** a long time.

> There is need to me to go to vacation.

This one is a little confusing. First, what's wrong:

- There is need **to** me -> this isn't grammatical.
- Same issue as before with go **to** vacation.

Here is a grammatical version of that sentence.

- There is **a** need **for** me to go **on a** vacation.

But it sounds a little odd to say it that way, so I would have just said:

- **I** need to go **on a** vacation.

So, here is how I would phrase this to my boss in a somewhat formal office setting. (Assume I am speaking this sentence, not writing it)

> Hi Mr./Mrs. `<Boss's last name>`. I've been working very hard lately, and haven't taken a vacation in a long time. I need to go on one soon.